# TypeScript: Casting result to custom type not working

Tags: typescript, casting

I have the Person type defined as follows

```
import moment from "moment";

export default class Person {
    constructor() {
        this.id = -1;
        this.name = "";
        this.dob = new Date();
        this.gender = "M";
        this.photo = "";
        this.salary = 0.0;
    }

   public id: number;
   public name: string;
   public dob: Date;
   public get dobString(): string{
        return moment(this.dob).toString();
   };
   public gender: string;
   public photo: string;
   public salary: number;
}
```

In the Person type above you can see that I have a read-only property **dobString()** that pretty much returns the date in string format.

Now I have a get method that returns the collection of records. I 'm casting the collection to `<Person[]>` but the result is not including the property **dobString()**. Can you please verify below my code and let me know what I'm missing?

```
getAll (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    var pageNumber = req.query.pageNumber;
    var pageSize = req.query.pageSize;

    db.query("CALL person_selectall(?, ?, @total); SELECT @total as TotalRecords;", [pageNumber, pageSize], (err: Error, rows: any[], fields: any) => {
        let result = new PageResult<Person>(pageSize, pageNumber, 0);

        if (!err) {
            result.IsSuccessful = true;
            result.TotalRecords = rows[2][0].TotalRecords;
            result.Data = <Person[]> rows[0];//result.Data is of type Person[]
            res.send(result);
        } else {
            result.IsSuccessful = false;
            result.TotalRecords = 0;
            result.ReasonForFailure = JSON.stringify(err);
            result.Data = [];
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**Update (20-Sep-2019)**

For now, I have implemented using the Map method (see below). Let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

```
const personArray = rows[0].map((row: any) => {
                const person = new Person();
                person.Id = row.id;
                person.Name = row.name;
                person.Gender = row.gender;
                person.Dob = row.dob;
                person.DobString = moment(person.Dob).format(config.get("format.date"));
                person.Photo = row.photo;
                person.Salary = row.salary;
                person.CreatedDate = row.createddate;
                person.CreatedDateString = moment(person.CreatedDate).format(config.get("format.datetime"));
                person.ModifiedDate = row.modifieddate;
                person.ModifiedDateString = person.ModifiedDate === null ? null : moment(person.ModifiedDate).format(config.get("format.datetime"));
                return person;
            });
            result.Data = personArray;
```

Thanks,
Hemant.

Answer (score 0):

`result.Data = <Person[]> rows[0];`

Remember that when typescript gets transpiled, all the type annotations just disappear and you're left with javascript that says `result.Data = rows[0]`. That code won't add any properties to the object that weren't already there.

The purpose of using a type assertion like `<Person[]>` isn't to make any changes to the data. The purpose is to tell typescript "i know better than you do, so don't check my types here". If you truly do know better than typescript does, then that can be ok. But if you assert that the object has a dobString function when in fact it does not, typescript will just trust you and will not be able to point out the error.

Comment: So is there a way around so that my result includes all members of my custom type? If so, can you please share the snippet to achieve this?

Comment: Well, if this were just javascript, what would you want to do? Probably call `new Person` one or more times, passing in data from `rows`. I'm not sure exactly what code you'd want because i don't know the structure that rows has, and your Person constructor doesn't look like its set up to be passed in properties.

Comment: Looks like I will have to do mapping of data from rows to my custom type collection in a loop. Let me know if there is a better way around

Comment: I have updated my request with a temporary solution.